# Why does the standard disallow an explicit destructor call with ~ preceded by the template keyword and followed by a qualified name?

Tags: c++, destructor, language-design, explicit-destructor-call

The standard rules:

[[temp.names]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#6)

> A name prefixed by the keyword template shall be followed by a template argument list or refer to a class template or an alias template. The latter case is deprecated ([depr.template.template]). The keyword template shall not appear immediately before a ~ token (as to name a destructor).

This prohibits the use of the `template` keyword.

[[expr.ref]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#1)

> A postfix expression followed by a dot . or an arrow ->, optionally followed by the keyword template, and then followed by an id-expression, is a postfix expression. The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated;53 the result of that evaluation, together with the id-expression, determines the result of the entire postfix expression.

[[expr.prim.id.unqual]/nt:unqualified-id](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#nt:unqualified-id):

> unqualified-id: ... ~ type-name ~ decltype-specifier ...

*type-name* can never be qualified names, so this prohibits the use of it.

So if I want to use `std::string` in the destructor, I can only do this:

```
std::string str;
str.std::string::~string();
new (&str) std::string;
```

or:

```
std::string str;
using std::string;
str.~string();
new (&str) std::string;
```

But `str.~std::string();` isn't valid.

Why is there such rules?

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you want to explicitly call destructor? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If you want to explicitly call a std::string destructor use `auto str_ptr = std::make_unique<std::string>()` and `str_ptr.reset()`  to delete the string. Otherwise just use the scope rules for C++ lifecycle of non dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: Consider adding the language lawyer tag if you are specifically asking for quotes in the standard.

Comment: You know `str.~basic_string();` works, right? I don't understand what syntax you're proposing.

Comment: Using `template` there would simply be redundant, see https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3.1. The only reason it exists at all is to make a non-default choice in parsing of `<` after dependent names, but with `~` there can't be an ambiguity. So why should it be allowed? A qualified name is not allowed since `~` basically works like it was part of the identifier naming the destructor. It can be qualified before the `~` as you are demonstrating.

Comment: *Why is there such rules?*  What kind of rules would you want?  I complained about C++ rules once, and Bjarne Stroustrup's response was "If you don't like the language, feel free to make your own language.  I did."

Comment: @Eljay Did I say I don't like the language? I just hope some unreasonable rules can be improved.

Comment: @user17732522 But why an unqualified typedef can be used after ~ and a qualified one cannot? I don't think it's good.

Comment: @Blackteahamburger I think that is only allowed because it is necessary to make generic code work in which the type is only known by an alias or template parameter. Such code should still be able to call the destructor. It would have probably been better if the destructor had a unique name not depending on the name of the class, then all of this wouldn't be an issue. I am not sure what Bjarne Stroustrup's original rationale was for choosing the `~classname` syntax for the destructor.

Comment: *I just hope some unreasonable rules can be improved.*  This isn't a great forum for that.  The people here are helping one another answer questions, we (collectively here) are not WG21 involved in improving and evolving the language.

Comment: I think this is not a [tag:language-lawyer] but [tag:language-design] since you're not asking about quote from standard but the reason.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) to do it

```
void foo(){
    std::string str;
    std::destroy_at(&str);
    std::construct_at(&str);
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it looks to me like the question seems to be specifically about the name lookup rules and not necessarily about fixing a problem. The question provides working code.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue here is that `std::string` is not a class - it is only an alias for `std::basic_string`.

So the type of `str` is actually `std::basic_string<char>` and **not** `std::string`.

`std::string` is not visible during member lookup inside `std::basic_string`, because it is not part of the class.
So if you want to use `~string` you would either have to make it visible for unqualified lookup (i.e. via `using std::string;`) or prefix it (`str.~std::string::~string();`).

The only destructor that member lookup can find is `std::basic_string::~basic_string()`, so this would be the one you would need to use:

```cpp
str.~basic_string();
```

Comment: I think OP probably also ask why `str.~std::string();` is not valid. (just my guess)

Comment: Although `std::string` isn't a class, it's a typedef. I want to ask why an unqualified typedef can be used after `~` and a qualified one cannot.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, you can also call it in other ways

```cpp
void foo(){
    std::string str;
    str.~basic_string();
    new (&str) std::string;
}

void foo_explicit_type(){
    std::string str;
    str.~basic_string<char>();
    new (&str) std::string;
}

void foo_alias(){
    using X = std::string;
    std::string str;
    str.~X();
    new (&str) std::string;
}
```

---

The relevant text is (also) at [[class.dtor]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#17)

> In an explicit destructor call, the destructor is specified by a `~`
> followed by a `type-name` or `decltype-specifier` that denotes the
> destructor's class type.
>
> [Example 1:
>
> ```
> struct B {
>   virtual ~B() { } 
> }; 
> struct D : B {   
>   ~D() { }
> };
>
> D D_object; 
> typedef B B_alias; 
> B* B_ptr = &D_object;
>
> void f() {
>   D_object.B::~B();             // calls B's destructor  
>   B_ptr->~B();                  // calls D's destructor  
>   B_ptr->~B_alias();            // calls D's destructor  
>   B_ptr->B_alias::~B();         // calls B's destructor  
>   B_ptr->B_alias::~B_alias();   // calls B's destructor 
> }
> ```
>
> — end example]